# Convert html table to pdf using jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I want to convert html table data as PDF file using jqGrid or some other simple Javascript / JQuery functions.

I have tried this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21496606/3428816

and

http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/export/pdf/default.php

But it is not working for me, because in this, they used PHP to creating PDF.

I want to generate PDF file without communicating with the server.

Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may have luck using [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf).