# how to select all records in the grid in order to export the data

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to select all the data present in the jqgrid table in order to export in to an excel file. But the data present in the first page of the grid is only getting exported. i.e., if a total of 25 records are present in the grid and 5 records are present in the first page, then only first 5 records are getting exported.

The following code is responsible for displaying records 'only' in the first page of the grid..

var gridData = $("#list").jqGrid('getRowData');

The following code is responsible for displaying records present in all the pages in the grid..

var gridData1 =jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');

how to use the above code such that I can select all the records present in the grid. also, I am trying to apply filter on the records  present in the grid. In such a case, how to get the filtered number of records in order to export them..?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it server side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#list').jqGrid({
        caption: "test",
             // ...
        }).navGrid(
             // ...
                }).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager', {
                    caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-print", title: "export",
                    onClickButton: function () {
                        $("#list").jqGrid('excelExport', { url: 'path......' });
                    }
                });
    });
</script>
```

`excelExport` method, sends the current page number, sort field, filtering, etc to the specified url. now you have time to process these parameters and create a new output.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try below script and function:

<script type='text/javascript'>

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
      , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
      , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
      , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function (table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.outerHTML }
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})();


$(document).ready(function () {
    ...declare & setup the jqGrid with 'big row page', e.g. ...
        rowNum: 9999,
        rowList: [50, 100, 200, 9999],
    .........then add below navigation button after setup the grid...
    $("#list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', pgrid1, {caption:"Download",title:"Download report contents", buttonicon :'ui-icon-circle-arrow-s',
        onClickButton:function(){
            tableToExcel('list', 'export data')
        } 
    });
```

}

</script>

Alternatively, another way to exporting can refer to related question:
[How to enable jQgrid to Export data into PDF/Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494761/how-to-enable-jqgrid-to-export-data-into-pdf-excel)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion.. but I am specifically expecting all the paginated present in the grid to be selected, even after applying **filters**.. if i get all the rows, then I guess I could handle it with my customized export button..see just for reference:I am using below snippets for applying filters:'function ApplyFilters { 
 ....
  var myfilter = {
   groupOp: "AND",
   rules: []
  };
  var myfilterWithoutDateOROperation = {
   groupOp: "OR",
   rules: []
  };   ...}' ...