# How to export HTML content with grid using jqGrid?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid to export a HTML page to PDF. The default behavior of the jqGrid is to export the grid. But I need to export the entire HTML page not only the grid. How can I achieve this this?

Comment: useful link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494761/how-to-enable-jqgrid-to-export-data-into-pdf-excel

Comment: If you need to "export the page" content to pdf then you should probably just print to device, which generates the PDF file. For example I have on my client "Microsoft Print to PDF" and I can print from the web browser to the printer and to generate pdf. I can choose some options (headers, color/black-white, page-size, printing of pictures and so on). There are some technologies which allow to render the page on the server if it's required. One can print the rendered page to PDF on the server side too. All above seems to me independent from jqGrid question.